# undo/redo event binding

Tags: jquery, html

I found some interesting javascript undo managers and –of course– we have the one that will be eventually implemented in the browser with HTML5.

Now, what I'm not sure about is how to capture user actions meant to trigger 'undo' with jQuery to drive the UndoManager:

- Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+Shift+Z
- Cmd+Z,  Cmd+Shift+Z
- User clicking on the *Edit>Undo* or *Edit>Redo* menu in their browsers

My first stab at it would be this:

```
function keypress(e){
  if (e.metaKey) {
    Collage.console(e);
    switch(e.keyCode){
    case 122: // Mac
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        undoManager.redo(e);
      } else {
        undoManager.undo(e);
      }
    case 26: // PC
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        undoManager.redo(e);
      } else {
        undoManager.undo(e);
      }
    }
  }
};

$('#my-thing-with-undos').bind('keypress', keypress);
```

but how do I ensure that the (modern) browser's Edit menu keeps up with the program?

I really don't want the browser to attempt to figure out what and how to undo in that region or, at least, not to perform an edit to it (it's a `contenteditable = true` region).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can trigger default browser events...

that in mind use an `array` to store ever keystroke of a particular time. e.g.

if i type "hello world " which in a second or if i continuesly keep typing keep recording the characters. when the users stops typing more than a second then push it to an array that way u have more control of the changes.

another thing is that this is a bad feeling. but im sure that 26 and 122 does not stand for ctrl + z most likely it's for the z it self or the control.

Comment: `if (e.metaKey)` on line 2 should ensure that Control or Command are down.

Comment: I don't this works unless you block the browser's default behavior somewhere.